# Deployed contract failed to execute

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, web3js

I have a contract here:

pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

```
contract Charity{

    mapping (address => uint) public coinBalanceOf;
    event CoinTransfer(address sender, address receiver, uint amount);

    function charity(uint supply){

        coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] = supply;
    }


    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns (bool sufficient)
    {

        if (coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] < amount) return false;

        coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;
        coinBalanceOf[receiver]   += amount;

        CoinTransfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);

        return true;

    }

}
```

When I deploy using `web3 1.0.0-beta` with

```
import * as fs       from 'fs'       ;
import * as solc     from 'solc'     ;
import * as Web3     from 'web3'     ; 

var web3   = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));


var contract_path : string = "../solidity/contracts/Charity.sol"
const input       = fs.readFileSync(contract_path)
const output      = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);
var contract_name = ":" + pr.last(contract_path.split("/")).split(".")[0]
const bytecode    = output.contracts[contract_name].bytecode
const abi_        = JSON.parse(output.contracts[contract_name].interface);

web3.eth.getAccounts().then(accounts => {

    var coinbase = accounts[0];
    var receiver = accounts[1];

    // create contract
    var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi_, coinbase,
        {
            from    : coinbase,
            gasPrice: "2000000"
        });


    var deployedContract = myContract.deploy({

        data: '0x' + bytecode,

    }).send({

        from: coinbase,
        gas : 1500000 ,
        gasPrice: '30000000000000'            

    }, (err, hash) => {

        if (err) { console.log("error on deployment: ", err) }
        console.log("Hash: ", hash)

    })


    myContract.methods.sendCoin(receiver, 7000000).send({ 

        from: coinbase,
        gas: 100000,
        gasPrice: '10000000'
    }, (err,val) => {
            if (err) { console.log(err) }
            else {
                console.log("sent coin: ", val)
            }
        })
    .then(console.log)  

});
```

However when I deployed it on a private blockchain that is mining, I see no changes in the receiver's balance.

I followed the answer below to pass the supply argument into the contract, however it is still not executing. It may be due to a timing issue, so I moved the `sendCoin` function to the callback as follows, but it is still not executing:

```
   var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi_, coinbase,
        {
            from    : coinbase,
            gasPrice: "2000000",
        });

    /**
        maybe there should be a callback up there ----^ ???
    */

    var deployedContract = myContract.deploy({

        data: '0x' + bytecode,
        arguments: [2406927999999]  // this is not sending
        // web3.eth.getBalance(coinbase)] note the raw number gets error: number-to-bn
        // is it because it's too big?

    }).send({

        from: coinbase,
        gas : 1500000 ,
        gasPrice: '30000000000000'            

    }, (err, hash) => {

        if (err) { console.log("error on deployment: ", err) }


        console.log("contract deployed with Hash: [REDACTED]")


    }).then((v) => {

            /**
                maybe this should happen in the callback?

            */
            myContract.methods.sendCoin(receiver, 70000000000).send({ 

                from: coinbase,
                gas : 100000  ,
                gasPrice: '10000000'

            }, (err,val) => {
                    if (err) { console.log(err) }
                    else {
                        console.log("---------------------------------------")
                        console.log("sent coin: ", val)
                        console.log("---------------------------------------")

                    }
            })
            console.log(".then callback with value.options: ", v.options)

            console.log('=====================================================')



    })

});
```

Comment: I don't see where you're initializing the `supply` when deploying the contract. `coinBalanceOf[msg.sender]` will always be 0 causing `sendCoin()` to simply return. Also, there's no point in returning a value from a non-constant function. You won't receive that in your client. Replace `if (coinBalanceOf[msg.sender] < amount) return false;` with `require(coinBalance[msg.sender >= amount);`.

Comment: where do you initialize the supply? The API has changed a lot since: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Contract-Tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the value for `supply` when initializing the contract. You can pass it in like this:

```
var deployedContract = myContract.deploy({
  data: '0x' + bytecode,
  arguments: [999999999]
}).send({
  from: coinbase,
  gas : 1500000 ,
  gasPrice: '30000000000000'            
}, (err, hash) => {
  if (err) { console.log("error on deployment: ", err) }
  console.log("Hash: ", hash)
})
```

See the docs for deploy [here](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#deploy) to see how to pass parameters into the contract constructor.

Also, make sure you capitalize `Charity` in your function name to match the name of the contract (otherwise it's not a constructor).

Comment: Ok @Adam Kipnis I ran it as you said, however the contract still failed to execute. I am beginning it might be a timing issue with the asyncs. For the sake of testing this hypothesis I moved the `myContract.methods.sendCoin` to the `.then` callback in `var deployedContract = ...`, however it is still not executing. Any thoughts? I added the code in the question above

Comment: I think you're on the right track with your asyncs. Is your function in the `then` block executing? If so, what happens if you change `myContract.methods.sendCoin` to `v.methods.sendCoin`? The parameter passed in to that function (that you have called `v`) is the new contract instance with the contract address now set after a successful deploy.

Comment: I get and error: `Error: Provider not set or invalid`. May I ask you to provide an answer that would work? Or explain what happens when a contract is deployed? What is the difference between myContract, deployedContract, and v? It is very difficult to understand the operational semantics of what is going on.

Comment: furthermore, the timing issue is confusing because I don't see it addressed in the example in the docs: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html